# How can I display a list of pages and the template used by each?

Tags: templates

I want to display a list of pages and the template used by each.

The code I’m currently using is below, but the result is a bit verbose.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT post_title, meta_value
FROM $wpdb->posts a
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
WHERE a.post_type = 'page'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
AND b.meta_key = '_wp_page_template'
";

$pages = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($pages);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The output is…

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_title] => Notes
        [meta_value] => default
    )
```

I want to simplify it to something like…

```
[1] Notes => default
```

Comment: Is your issue entirely with array composition? That's on plain PHP side and typically not considered in scope here as unspecific to WordPress.

Comment: @Rarst... you're probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this quick piece of code, it doesnt output to array though.

```
    $args = array( 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'sort_column' => 'post_title', 'sort_order' => 'desc');
    $templates = get_pages($args);
    foreach ( $templates as $template){
        $templatePage  = $template->meta_value;
        $templateName  = $template->post_name;

    echo "Named Template: {$templateName} - - {$templatePage}\n";
    }
```